# TLS MAC message verification

Tags: python, macos, ssl, hmac, sha256

I'm developing a SSL de-cipher in python but I'm having some problems on HMAC verification:

I've extracted all keyring related material (client IV, MAC, Key and Server IV, MAC, key). 
When I receive the first Application_Data message (0x17), I am able to decrypt it, but unable to verify message integrity.

On RFC 2246 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt), tells:

> The MAC is generated as:
>
> ```
>    HMAC_hash(MAC_write_secret, seq_num + TLSCompressed.type +
>                  TLSCompressed.version + TLSCompressed.length +
>                  TLSCompressed.fragment));
> ```
>
> where "+" denotes concatenation.
>
> seq_num
>          The sequence number for this record.
>
> hash
>          The hashing algorithm specified by
>          SecurityParameters.mac_algorithm.

Taking this as an example:

```
Chosen cipher_suite is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256

client_mac = "some random stuff"
message_type = 0x17
message_version = 0x0303
encrypted_message_length = 1184 (IV|Message|MAC|Offset)
decrypted_message_length = 1122 (removing IV, MAC and offset)
message = "some message of length 1122"
```

- client_mac is extracted from keyring_material
- message_type is 0x17, because as an Application_data message type, the correct value should be 0x17
- message version is 0x0303 as it's TLS 1.2
- message length is 1122, removing preceding IV, offset and MAC verification, message, gets a final length of 1122
- seq_number is 1 as it's the first message

HMAC_SHA256 calculation, in python, is as follows:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
hmac.new(<client_mac>,label+message,hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

My question is, how do I calculate label?
As RFC mentions, "+" denotes concatenation, but concatenation of what

- HEX values converted to string

  - "1" + "17" + "0303" + "462"
- INT values converted to strings

  - "1" + "23" + "771" + "1122"

And other thing to mention, TLSCompressed.version means:

- 0x0303
- 771
- "1.2"
- "12"
- "TLS 1.2"

In this maillist (http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg14357.html) I found a supposed clarification of MAC values,

> ```
>    MAC(MAC_write_key, seq_num +
>        TLSCipherText.type +
>        TLSCipherText.version +
>        length of ENC(content + padding + padding_length) +
>        IV +
>        ENC(content + padding + padding_length));
> ```
>
> where the length is encoded as two bytes in the usual way.

but it makes no sense to me, because it's useless to re-encode decrypted values to check to compute MAC. And from last line *"where length is encoded as two bytes in the usual way"*, does it means that I should use

> struct.pack("!H",length)

Then remove "\x" and use this value? or should I encode this value in HEX and then concatenate it?

I'm a bit lost, because RFC are not clear about how values should be used.

I've been trying several combinations (even brute forcing), but none of them worked, I hope you can light my way.

Answer (score 4):

Well, after diggin' a bit I've managed to solve the issue.

RFC 5246, in section 6.2.3.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.1)

> The MAC is generated as:
>
> ```
>   MAC(MAC_write_key, seq_num +
>                         TLSCompressed.type +
>                         TLSCompressed.version +
>                         TLSCompressed.length +
>                         TLSCompressed.fragment);
> ```
>
> where "+" denotes concatenation.

But it does not points the data size, either representation format (hex, string...).

The way every field must be represented is as follows:

- seq_num:

  - Description: A int counter, starting in 0, which will be incremented every frame received or sended. For a TCP Session, two seq_numbers must be used, one for the server and other for the client, incrementing everytime each of them sends a frame.
  - Representation: This value must be represented as *Unsigned Long Long* with 8 bytes
  - Representation example:
    `struct.pack("!Q",seq_num)`
- TLSCompressed.type

  - Description: This field is extracted from TLS Record layer (the encrypted payload). For example, if it's an *Application Data* frame, we must use 0x17.
  - Representation: This value must be represented as *Signed Char*, with 2 bytes.
  - Representation example:
    `struct.pack("!b",TLSCompressed.type)`
- TLSCompressed.version

  - Description: This field is also extracted from TLS Record layer (the encrypted payload). For example, if the frame is transferred using TLS 1.2, we must use it's hex representation 0x0303.
  - Representation: This value must be represented as *Unsigned Short*, with 2 bytes.
  - Representation example:
    `struct.pack("!H",TLSCompressed.version)`
- TLSCompressed.length

  - Description: This field represents the actual length of the **decrypted** payload.
  - Representation: This value must be represented as *Unsigned Short*, with 2 bytes.
  - Representation example:
    `struct.pack("!H",TLSCompressed.length)`
- TLSCompressed.fragment

  - Description: This field **is the actual **decrypted payload.**
  - Representation: This value must be represented as a string

As a python example, the HMAC hashing will be as follows for our previous example:

```
hmac_digest = hmac.new(mac_secret,'',digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
hmac_digest.update(struct.pack('!QbHH',seq_num,TLSCompressed.type,TLSCompressed.version, len(decrypted)))
hmac_digest.update(decrypted)
hmac_digest.digest()
```